# Vue.js dynamic <style> with variables

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to add the dynamic variable in style?

I mean something like:

```
<style>
    .class_name {
        background-image({{project.background}});
    }
    @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        .class_name {
            background-image({{project.background_retina}});
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: CSS is static.  

If your style is really complex, maybe you will need some CSS pre-processor.

Comment: an [article](https://increment.com/frontend/a-users-guide-to-css-variables/) on css variable and sass variable calculation function `calc()`

Answer (score 83):

With [Vue.js 3.2](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html) you can do [State-Driven Dynamic CSS](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css) like this:

```html
<template>
    <h1 id="script">Script</h1>
    <h1 id="scriptSetup">Script setup</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        colorFromScript: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<script setup>
const colorFromScriptSetup = 'green'
</script>

<style>
  #script {
      color: v-bind('colorFromScript')
  }

  #scriptSetup {
      color: v-bind('colorFromScriptSetup')
  }
</style>
```

[See an implementation here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-js-dynamic-style-with-variables?file=src/App.vue)

[v-bind in CSS Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css)

Comment: This is the best solution for those using `Vue 3`.

Comment: this doesn't work with nested scss selectors

Comment: Also, work for Vue 2.7

Answer (score 68):

I faced the same problem. I have been trying to use a background color value from a database. I find out a good solution to add a background color value on inline CSS which value I set from database.

```
<img :src="/Imagesource.jpg" alt="" :style="{'background-color':Your_Variable_Name}">
```

Comment: Works well without the { and } in the :style

Comment: this does not work if you use lib. I need apply to apply style to the child of child component.

Comment: you can also write ```background-color``` in snake-case, if you don't want to enclose it around extra pair of inverted commas. It looks neat and saves time 
```:style="{backgroundColor:Your_Variable_Name}"```

Comment: @MuhammadNaufil not snake_case but camelCase, other than that good advice :)

Comment: How would you do this with something like transform: rotateZ(0);?

Comment: I found a solution to my comment above. If anyone finds this in the future, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381670/vuejs-transform-rotate-style-inline)

Answer (score 42):

The best way to include dynamic styles is to use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var). To avoid inline styles while gaining the benefit (or necessity—*e.g.*, user-defined colors within a data payload) of dynamic styling, use a `<style>` tag inside of the `<template>` (so that values can be inserted by Vue). Use a [`:root` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) to contain the variables so that they are accessible across the CSS scope of the application.

Note that some CSS values, [like `url()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330075/is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-css-variables-with-url#42331003) cannot be interpolated, so they need to be complete variables.

Example ([Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) `.vue` with [ES6/ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) syntax):

```
<template>

<div>
  <style>
    :root {
      --accent-color: {{ accentColor }};
      --hero-image: url('{{ heroImage }}');
    }
  </style>
  <div class="punchy">
    <h1>Pow.</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</template>
<script>

export default {
  data() { return {
    accentColor: '#f00',
    heroImage: 'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png',
  }},
}

</script>
<style>

.punchy {
  background-image: var(--hero-image);
  border: 4px solid var(--accent-color);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
}
h1 {
  color: var(--accent-color);
}

</style>
```

Also created an alternate more involved runnable example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mickeymullin/pen/bKVWzg).

Comment: Tried your solution in the component with <Templates> and get this error: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.

Comment: This is the right idea, but as Nelly points out, Vue throws a warning or may even not load depending on version in use (minified Vue appears to allow this).

See Muthu's answer (specifically their Update section) or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280182/3268060) for a better solution

Comment: instead of putting the CSS variables in a `<style>` block, you can build an object with each variable name as the property along with its value as a computed prop or method. Then simply bind this object to the root element's `style` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately HTML validators will throw an error for <style> tags placed within a <div> tag.

Answer (score 18):

CSS `<style>` is static. I don't think you can do that... you might have to look for a different approach.

You can try using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). For example, (the code below is not tested)

```
<template>
    <div class="class_name" :style="{'--bkgImage': 'url(' + project.background + ')', '--bkgImageMobile': 'url(' + project.backgroundRetina + ')'}">
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    .class_name{
        background-image: var(--bkgImage);
    }
    @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
        all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
        all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
        all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
            .class_name {
                background-image: var(--bkgImageMobile);
            }
        }
</style>
```

Note: Only the latest browsers support *CSS variables*.

If you still see any issues with the `:style` in the template then try this,

```
<div :style="'--bkgImage: url(' + project.background + '); --bkgImageMobile: url(' + project.backgroundRetina + ')'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

As you are using Vue.js, use Vue.js to change the background, instead of CSS:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-instance',
    data: {
        rows: [
            {value: 'green'},
            {value: 'red'},
            {value: 'blue'},
        ],
        item:""
    },
    methods:{
        onTimeSlotClick: function(item){
            console.log(item);
            document.querySelector(".dynamic").style.background = item;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="item" v-on:change="onTimeSlotClick(item)">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option v-for="row in rows">
            {{row.value}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <div class='dynamic'>VALUE</div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div :style="{ background: item}">Another</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great but in an inline method, i cannot add a background for retina. I know that method.

Comment: You can add class, toggle, v-show, v-if to achieve this

Comment: I can do it with two div and class to show one div depends of retina or not. But.. It will load two images always. 

v-if or v-show sound good but how to check if we are on a retina display with v-if? Or how to check it in JS.. Maybe i will found solution in that way.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible. Vue.js does not support `style` tags in templates, but you can get around this by using a `component` tag. Untested pseudocode:

In your template:

```
<component type="style" v-html="style"></component>
```

In your script:

```
props: {
    color: String
}
computed: {
    style() {
        return `.myJSGeneratedStyle { color: ${this.color} }`;
    }
}
```

There are lots of reasons why you shouldn't use this method. It's definitely hacky and `:style=""` is probably better most of the time, but for your problem with media queries I think this is a good solution.

Comment: With Vue 2.6.11 I could not get the <component> to work so this answer may not work.

Answer (score 6):

## Vue 3 State-Driven Dynamic CSS Variables

I know this is a bit late and is using Vue.js 2, but as of now in Vue.js 3 you can create state-driven CSS variables.

You can now use your SFC (Single File Component) state data inside your styles tags using `v-bind()`.

You can read more about state-driven CSS variables [here](https://www.jsnow.io/javascript/vue/vue-dynamic-css), or read the Vue.js 3 documentation [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css).

Here is a code example

##### Example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="color" />
    <div class="user-input-color">
      {{ color }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    color: 'white'
  })
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.user-input-color {
  background-color: v-bind(color)
}
</style>
```

Here is a link to the [live example](https://vue-state-driven-css-variables-example.vercel.app/).

Links

- [JS Now Vue state-driven CSS variables](https://www.jsnow.io/javascript/vue/vue-dynamic-css)
- [Vue.js 3 Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css)
- [Live Example](https://vue-state-driven-css-variables-example.vercel.app/)

Comment: You need quotes to include the v-bind variable like v-bind('color').

Answer (score 5):

You can use the component tag offered by Vue.js.

```js
<template>
  <component :is="`style`">
    .cg {color: {{color}};}
  </component>
  <p class="cg">I am green</p> <br/>
  <button @click="change">change</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return { color: 'green' }
    },
    methods: {
      change() {this.color = 'red';}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Even if this could work, this Sz.'s answer here suggests that it might not be a good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154225/14008447

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and I figured out a hack which suits my needs (and maybe yours).

As `<style>` is contained in `<head>`, there is a way to make it work:

We generate the CSS content as a computed property based on the state of the page/component

```
computed: {
    css() {
        return `<style type="text/css">
         .bg {
            background: ${this.bg_color_string};
         }</style>`
    }
}
```

Now, we have our style as a string and the only challenge is to pass it to the browser.

I added this to my `<head>`

```
<style id="customStyle"></style>
```

Then I call the `setInterval` once the page is loaded.

```
 mounted() {
     setInterval(() => this.refreshHead(), 1000);
 }
```

And I define the refreshHead as such:

```
methods: {
   refreshHead() {
       document.getElementById('customStyle').innerHTML = this.css
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to write completely dynamic styles, so I used approach beyond Vue system:

```js
{
   // Other properties.
    watch: {
        myProp: {
            handler() {
                this.styleElement.innerHTML = this.myProp.css;
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.styleElement = this.document.createElement('style');
        this.styleElement.innerText = this.myProp.css;
        this.document.head.append(this.styleElement);
    },
    unmounted() {
        this.styleElement.remove();
    },
}
```

Though it may have some performace issues with CSS big enough.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, this is how you would do it in Vue.js and [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="dynamicImageURL" alt="" :style="'background-color':backgroundColor"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
           return {
                 dynamicImageURL='myimage.png',
                 backgroundColor='red',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Says "parsing error".

Answer (score 0):

I liked @mickey-mullin reply, but not everything worked entirely. The `url` missed `require`, even though the information in his post helped me a lot in my case.

`var()`, `url()`, multiple ternary operators (my own case - you shouldn't need it), I was able to do so for `background-image` in such a way:

**template**

```html
<div :style="[
  case1 ? { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/icon1.svg')})`} :
  case2 ? { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/icon2.svg')})`} :
  { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/default.svg')})` },
]" class="myClass">
```

**styles**

```css
div.myClass::before {
  background-image: var(--iconUrl);
}
```

Note: I didn't have to declare `iconUrl` in my `data()` -> `return`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do, even better if already using a framework / css variables.

By adding style to your html that would overwrite the root/variables according to loaded "dynamic css"

**In that case using css vars in your css**

```
<style>
.myTheme{
  color:var(--theme-color)
}
</style>
```

then having a computed property like:

```
computed:{
 accountTheme(){
  return {"--theme-color":this.themeColor}
 }
}
```

Then whatever method that would change such dynamic theme you do it

```
methods:{
 load(){
  ....
  this.themeColor="red"
 }
}
```

Apply that dynamic style to html element

```
<html :style="accountTheme"></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - if you add the style tags along with the definitions and it should work.

```html
<template>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div v-html="customStyle"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const customStyle = ref("<style>body{background:blue!important;}</style>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to embed multiple CSS rules when using progressive Vue.js (i.e. no npm / build step) using Vue's dynamic `<component>`:

```js
const MyComponent = {
  template:`<div>
    <component is="style" v-html="css"></component>
  </div>`,
  setup() {
     const css = `
        .animation-pulse {
            animation: pulse 2s infinite;
        }
        @keyframes pulse {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0.8);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(229, 62, 62, 1);
            }
            70% {
                transform: scale(1);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(229, 62, 62, 0);
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(0.8);
            }
        }`
     return { css }
  }
}
```