# vueJS transform rotate style inline

Tags: css, rotation, vuejs2, transform

I need to add to div rotate. I don't need animate, I just need to add it inline. Value of rotate is depend on data in vue component.

```
.
.
.
data(): function(){
 return{
  deg: 5
 }
}
.
.
.
```

I tryed:

```
v-bind:style="{ transform: rotate(deg) }"
v-bind:style="$transform: 'rotate('+deg+')'"
```

Maybe someone know, how it should to be in vue2?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually you need to make the transform value a string:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { turn: 0.5 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :style="{ transform: 'rotate('+ turn+'turn)'}"> Test </div>
</div>
```

But I adivse to use a compute properties:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { turn: 0.5 },
  computed: {
     style () {
        return { transform: 'rotate(' + this.turn + 'turn)'}
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :style="style"> Test </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

First tried inline style, it worked but was very finicky.  Computed was the way to go.  But also added the word "deg" in there...

```
   <img :style="style">

   computed: {
     style () {
     return { transform: 'rotate('+this.turn+'deg)'}
 }
```

},