# v-bind:style pseudo element :: after content icon

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap Vue ProgressBar. I need to add a pseudo element `::after` with content icon (from FontAwesome) to the element with class `.progress-bar`.  And I also want it to be dynamic. I have implemented steps in my ProgressBar(from 0 to 100) and I want this icon to go along with ProgressBar line when I click.

```
<b-progress v-bind:style="styleProgressBar" :value="counter" :max="max"></b-progress>
```

```
 export default {
        components:{
            'navbar':navbar
        },
        name: "myPage",
        data() {
            return {
                counter: 0,
                max: 100,
                step:1,
            }
        },
        methods:{
            prev() {
                this.step--;
            },
            next() {
                this.step++;
                if (this.counter < 100) {
                    this.counter += 34;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also saw this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```
<div v-bind:style="styleObject"></div>

data: {
  styleObject: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '13px'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you'd like to add one icon following the progress bar.

If so, check below demo, it uses one span simulate the icon, then bind `left` to move the icon.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    max: 100,
    intervalID: null
  },
  methods: {
    runTask: function () {      
      clearInterval(this.intervalID)
      this.counter = 0
      this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter = (this.counter+7)%this.max
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.badge {
  background-color:green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="runTask()">Run</button>
  <b-progress class="mt-1" :max="max" show-value>
     <b-progress-bar :value="counter" variant="success">
        <span class="badge" style="position:absolute;" :style="{'left':counter*100/max + '%'}" v-show="counter > 0">x</span>
     </b-progress-bar>
  </b-progress>
</div>
```

Comment: While a good answer, this doesn't OP's question about how to style a pseudo element. All this does is add an extra element and apply inline style to it.

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have a parent component:

```
<div id="parent">
  <ChildComponent id="child"> // Possibly from another library?
</div>

// renders ->

<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
     <div id="child-component-item">
        ::after
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The challenge is creating a binding for the `#child-component-item:after` selector.

We can use css vars to solve this problem, by "reaching into" the child component with some CSS. Note that you may have to use `::v-deep` if your style is `scoped`.

*parent-component.js*

```
<div id="parent-component" :style="{'--bgColor': bgColor}">
   <ChildComponent>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        bgColor: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
   #child-component-item:after {
      background-color: var(--bgColor)
   }
</style>
```

Comment: This worked for me. It keeps the style for that component if you want to use the component with different style props.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`css var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

And then `:style="{ '--varName': xxx}"`

Comment: More similar approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322875/vue-js-dynamic-style-with-variables

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, but for `::before`, and in combination with `var()`, `url()`, multiple ternary operators (my own case - you shouldn't need it), I was able to fix `background-image` in such a way:

**template**

```html
<div :style="[
  case1 ? { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/icon1.svg')})`} :
  case2 ? { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/icon2.svg')})`} :
  { '--iconUrl': `url(${require('../../../public/default.svg')})` },
]" class="myClass">
```

**styles**

```css
div.myClass::before {
  background-image: var(--iconUrl);
}
```

**Edit:** I didn't have to declare `iconUrl` in my `data()` -> `return`.