# how can I set dynamic inline-style to :after of an element in vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

My question is that I want to load a div `image-background` dynamically. How can I do this?

```
<div
      class="sub-service-box"
      v-for="item in serviceCategories[itemIndex].services"
      :key="item._id"
    >
      <div
        class="background-img"
        :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.imageUrl + ')' }"
      >
      </div>

    </div>
```

serviceCategories[itemIndex].services is an array that comes from API

Comment: Seemly your code hasn't problem. are you sure `item.imageUrl` load any image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS set background-image by data-image attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967890/css-set-background-image-by-data-image-attr)

Comment: As you cant set style of a pseudo element directly you need to pass it say a CSS variable that has the URL setting.

Comment: you can solve this problem after reading this [part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031052/11530419)

Answer (score -1):

Is `imageUrl` a remote `https` url, or a path to a static asset in your project?

If it's a remote url your code looks fine.

If it's a static asset in your project, you have to `require` it like this:

```html
<div
  class="sub-service-box"
  v-for="item in serviceCategories[itemIndex].services"
   :key="item._id"
>
  <div
    class="background-img"
     :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(item.imageUrl) + ')' }"
  >
  </div>
</div>
```