# Vue2 binding inside style tag isn't properly parsing

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been looking for ways to use variables within the style tag of a Vue file and have come across [this solution](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css). I have attempted to use it as can be seen in the code sample below

```
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: "test",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.backIm:before {
  ...
  background: v-bind(url);
  ...
}
</style>
```

However, despite seeming set up the exact same way as was done in the documentation, the `v-bind(url)` isn't interpreted when testing, as can be seen within the developer tools

[image: v-bind not being parsed in developer tools]

I've searched but not found anyone with this exact issue. If anyone could explain why this is incorrect, and provide a solution, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The documentation you are looking into is of Vue3. Vue2 does not support v-bind in CSS. However you can do this using var in Vue2. Have a look at this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625973/vue-js-v-bindstyle-pseudo-element-after-content-icon

Comment: Just make your  style scoped and it'll work

Comment: @NehaSoni I can't believe I didn't notice it's Vue3 exclusive. Thank you so much, the project is small enough where I believe my best option is migrating to Vue3, but I appreciate you providing an alternative solution.