# Vue 3 get props in style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, sass

I have some problems implementing props in style tag.
I have props like:

```
 props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
```

And I want to use label props in Style, like:

```
    <style scoped lang="scss">
      .class{
        color: label;
      }
    </style>
```

is that possible? Because it's not working like this

Idea is actually to make a call like:

```
.drop-color{
    color: map-get($var, label);
  }
```

This will work if I define it as;

```
.drop-color{
    color: map-get($var, 'blue');
  }
```

I just need to pass prop label instead.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872117/10000229

Answer (score 3):

With new script setup you're able to do it using `v-bind` of vue 3.2.x:

```html
<script setup>
import {defineProps} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
     icon: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
})


</script>
  <style scoped lang="scss">
      .class{
        color: v-bind(label);
      }
    </style>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks, but idea is to do something like color: map-get($products, v-bind(icon));  and this way it's  not working

Comment: please share the whole component code and the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. `v-bind` is runtime expression, whereas `map-get` and other SASS specific things are transpiled to CSS at build time. So, if the key of the map is not available at build time, it won't build correctly.

But, you can import SASS variables and maps into JS and use them instead.

I don't know if SASS's builtin `:export` supports maps, but if it doesn't you can use third party libraries like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-export