# how to add Vue props value to background-image

Tags: css, typescript, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm new in VueJS and I get confused to change background image from Vue props value.

I've created simple table from 'vue3-easy-data-table'.

**BaseTable.vue:**

```js
<template>
  <EasyDataTable>
...
  </EasyDataTable>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  changeImg: {
    type: String,
  }
})

</script>

<style>

.vue3-easy-data-table__message {
  
  background-image: url("`${v-bind("changeImg")}`");
  /*  background-image: var(--image-url); */
  /* background-image: url('@/assets/img/noDataMultiplierOnCity.svg'); */
 
}

</style>
```

**View.vue:**

```
<template>
<BaseTable
  :changeImg= "image"
  
/>     
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const image : string = "'@/assets/img/noDataMultiplierOnCity.svg'" 

</script>
```

I've tried solution from this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872002/in-vue-js-component-how-to-use-props-in-css](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but no gain.

Already tried as in the comments in the code, in this case I can just style the component in style tag cause the class is from 'vue3-easy-data-table' (maybe have another way to apply style to it?)

I want to make the background image from `BaseTable` so it can be reused in other file.

Comment: Please see edit to answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use an inline reactive style. For example you could give your script a method that convers the prop into a style, one that holds the image and any other defining features:

```html
<template>
  <EasyDataTable  :style="backgroundStyles(image)">
...
  </EasyDataTable>
</template>

<script setup>
  changeImg: {
    type: String,
  }
})

 const backgroundStyles = (img) => {
   return {
     'background-image': `url(${img})`,
     'background-size': 'cover'
   }
 }

</script>
```

[image]

code:

## App.vue

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import BaseTable from './BaseTable.vue'
import BaseTable2 from './BaseTable2.vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
const imageUrl = ref("https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/SWx64q2g3wax53Xz5H4QjS-970-80.jpg.webp");
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg">
  <BaseTable :image="imageUrl"/>
  <hr>
  <BaseTable2 :image="imageUrl"/>
</template>
```

## BaseTable.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="bkgrnd" :style="backgroundStyles(image)">
    <h2>
      Base Table
    </h2>
    <ul v-for="index in 8" :key="index">
      <li>Index: {{ index }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script setup>
 const props = defineProps(['image'])
 
 const backgroundStyles = (img) => {
   return {
     'background-image': `url(${img})`,
     'background-size': 'cover'
   }
 }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .bkgrnd {
    color: white;
    font-style: bold;
  }
</style>
```

---

## Solution using the prop in the CSS

Another way to do this can be to avoid inline styles and instead display the background image in the `<style>` CSS code.  To do this, I would use a computed property to create a URL from the prop, something like:

```javascript
const computedUrl = computed(() => {
  return `url(${props.image})`;
});
```

Code example,

## BaseTable2.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="bkgrnd">
    <h2>
      Base Table 2
    </h2>
    <ul v-for="index in 8" :key="index">
      <li>Index: {{ index }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps(['image'])

const computedUrl = computed(() => {
  return `url(${props.image})`;
});
</script>

<style scoped>
  .bkgrnd {
    color: white;
    font-style: bold;
    background-image: v-bind(computedUrl);
  }
</style>
```

Both examples can be found at the [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right and this example will help you

template:

```
<div :style="styleExample" />
```

script:

```
let styleExample = { 'width': props.examplePro }
```