# How to set prop-based css variable in vuejs 2.x and use it in a parent component

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use this approach ([In vue.js component, how to use props in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872002/in-vue-js-component-how-to-use-props-in-css)) to put prop-based variables in my css code.

I have a component called `TouchLayout`, and I would like to edit a css property belonging to a `<main>` tag that is a grand parent of my component. Usually I put my css variables in :root, but for this task I think I can't do it.

So I am currently setting this computed prop in my component:

```
computed: {
    cssProps() {
      return {
        '--main-padding-bottom': this.hasFooter ? '40px' : '20px'
      }
    }
  }
```

and in template I use

```
<template>
  <div class="h-full" :style="cssProps">
...
```

But my css var isn't recognized:

```
<style>
main.v-main {
  padding-bottom: var(--main-padding-bottom);
```

Is it possible to set a css var in a child component and, by the magic of unscoped css, use it in a grand parent?

Comment: You can't do that. It's not related to Vue, just common HTML/CSS. CSS vars are hierarchical, in order for cssProps to affect main.v-main it should be added to main or its parent.

Comment: Thanks! I have a different approach in mind, but if that fails I'll try to $ref a root component and put the var in there.